# Does anyone know where I can find examples of a SP 2013 Foundation Site?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

We are going from 2007 to 2013 Foundation and the result has been, well, frankly, frightful. I need to find some samples of great looking SP Foundation sites to show the possibilities to my management. I have googled without success.